# MySQL Syntax not returning result

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, date-format

I have this column (Created) in my database that has a `datetime` attribute. I want to get rows of record in the same year and month bracket using `$_GET['']` from my hyperlink.

What the link echoes to the header is the `$datetime = strtotime($row['Created']);` from a previous page.

```
 $datetime = strtotime($row['Created']);
 $tday = date("F, Y", $datetime);
 <a href="news.php?year='.$datetime.'">'.$tday.'</a>
//It returns this for example 1437476308
```

In my fetch_array statement

```
if(isset($_GET['year'])){
  $year= mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, strip_tags($_GET['year']));
//For example $year ends up with 1437476308
SELECT * 
  FROM Posts 
  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(Created, '%Y-%m')=DATE_FORMAT({$year}, '%Y-%m');
```

The query returns 0 rows when it should return 2 rows. I have used MYSQL console I get the same 0 rows, There is something am not doing right.

Comment: What does `$year` look like?  I don't see where it is being set.

Comment: Is `$year` passed via GET? In your case the paramter year is an Unix-Timestamp, because you are calling `strtotime`. If you want it like that, you can change your SQL condition to `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME({$year}), '%Y-%m');`

Comment: I am pretty sure that query would not compile the where clause is wrong and needs a column name to compare the variable to i.e. `WHERE Created = DATE_FORMAT({$year}, '%Y-%m');` But I am not sure how you intend to create a Year-Month from just a `$year` assuming `$year` contains something like `2015`

Comment: @mario.klump answer solved it, I needed the FROM-UNIXTIME function to get it to work. Thanks for contributing

Answer (score 1):

I would change your code with

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $row['Created']);

echo '<a href="news.php?date=' . $dateTime->format('Y-m-01') . '">' . $dateTime->format('F, Y') . '</a>';
```

and the query would be:

```
if(isset($_GET['date'])){
    $firstDay = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['date']);

    $query = "SELECT * 
              FROM projects 
              WHERE Date BETWEEN '$firstDay' AND LAST_DAY('$firstDay')";
}
```

Also, don't forget to add an index to the `Date` column in `projects` table